# How to organize HTML file structure?

Tags: html, organization

Let's say I have completed my index.html file with all the CSS and JavaScripts and I want to create some other ones like: "contact", "about us", "music" etc.

They all have to go into the same root folder as the index.html. Well this is ok with me since there's not that many, but what about sub-categories? Like in music I would like to have 10 different genres.html and inside that, 20 more artists.html and so on. This would entirely cluster my root folder. And putting them into a sub-folder doesn't work either, because then all the links to the centralized resources (like: CSS files, images, JavaScript) break. And having to manually adjust every absolute path is also a pain. I gave `<base>` a try but it messed other things up.

What is the best and simplest way to organize your website's page structure (preferably without a CMS)?

Comment: Is there an possibility you could use PHP? Or is that not possible?

Comment: @Mathlight Yes php is also a possibility. But I only have basic knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

If PHP is an possibility, you could use an very simple script like this:

`{root}/index.php`

```
<?php

if(!isset($_GET['route'])){     // If no route is given
    require_once 'pages/index.html';    // Load the default index page
}else if(!file_exists('pages/' . $_GET['route'] . '.html')){        // If an route is given, check if the page exists
    require_once 'pages/404.html';      // If not, load an 404 page
}else{
    require_once 'pages/' . $_GET['route'] . '.html';   // Or else load the given route
}
```

The url's will then be something like this:

`www.yoursite.com/index.php?route=index` (index.html inside the pages folder)

`www.yoursite.com/index.php?route=contact` (pages/contact.html)

`www.yoursite.com/index.php?route=catalog/category/something/list` (pages/catalog/category/something/list.html)

This is very simple and basic PHP using so called `$_GET` variables ([More about that here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) )

All the requests will be handeld by the index.php inside the root of your website.

Because of that, your include link for your JS and CSS files, will always be from the root directory. Therefore, you don't need to worry about all the different paths.

If you need more help, just ask.

**Update**

Your folder structure could be something like this than:

```
root/
    css/
    js/
    img/
    pages/
        music/
            artist.html
        something/
            else/
                stuff.php
        index.html
        contact.html
    index.php
```

And instead of doing `$_GET['route'] . 'html'`, you could also use just `$_GET['route']` and append the file extension to the url. This way you can use all different types of file extensions. (`www.yoursite.com/index.php?route=music/artist.php`)

Or you could just change .html to .php. That's all up to you!

Comment: Thank you for that quick response! I will mark your answer as soon as I understand the php code :)

Comment: @Haeri, no problem, take your time. Nothing more important than understanding the code your using... If you need any help with it, just let me know...

Comment: 3 things:     1. There is a small error in the else if line. the if statement is not closed (it needs two brackets "))" )    2. Can you give me the exact paths where I have to store the files? like: "root/index.php", "root/pages/index.html", "root/pages/music/artist.html"...    3. Is it possible for the files to be .php files? because I would like to do some "include" so that I don't have to go through 20 files when I have changed a small text in the footer?

Comment: @Haeri, nice catch on the missing closing if. Just made it out of my head, so must have overlooked it.

I've added an folder structure example for clarification. You're free to just edit everything to your own feelings. It's just an very simple basic PHP script to do stuff. Nothing fancy, and when you'll begin working with OOP, you'll be doing this thing (routing) more and more, and in an nicer and cleaner way...

Comment: Thank you so much for the update. But I still have a question: I have my files structured exactly how you described it. So my next assumption why it doesn't work is, that my anker tags are linking wrongly. Could you give me an example how I would for example link to artist.html?

Comment: Your link would then be something like this: `www.yourdomain.com/index.php?route=music/artist.html` (with the .html or without, depending on which route solution your using.)  if you need more (personal) help, you could contact me at Difrncestick@gmail.com and I'll try to  help you put as much as I can.

Comment: I finally managed to make this work! I didn't like how I had to write "index.php?route=var" so I decided to just pass the path "music/songs" and let .htaccess do the magic. But I ran into a big problem, where the resources could not be loaded in the subpages. But now finally I discovered that I simply had to put a "/" in front of the path of the resources. I would like to thank you again for your help and ask you if it would be ok if I would write an in depth answer, where I use your index.php trick and expand on it with .htaccess, to have this solution as a reference for me and others.

Comment: @Haeri, Sure thing! Glad that you have find the perfect solution for your problem. I by myself use `.htaccess` all the time, to do this. But i thought that would be out of the scope for your solution for now. But that is indeed the best / nicest way to do it. I'm glad you find that out on your own!

Comment: Hy Mat. I have sent you an email but I am pretty sure it landed in your spam filter... So I hope to see a reply from you :)

Answer (score 0):

I use to design my page's structure with the help of PHP.
Here's how I would do it:

**Template page**

you can make your own template and only fill in the content:

```
<?php
$root = "";
require_once $root . 'class/page.php';
$page = new Page();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <?php
    $page->metaTags();
    $page->metaDescription("");
    $page->metaKeywords("");
    $page->defaultStyles();
    $page->addStyle("styleName");
    $page->title("your page title");
    $page->defaultScripts();  
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $page->navigation();
        $page->header();
        $page->openContainer();
        $page->openContentSection();
    ?>
    Your page content
    <?php
        $page->closeContentSection();
        $page->closeContainer();
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the page class will handle the layout and the links so you can make your changes in 1 place and still affect all the pages in your site.

**Page class**

```
class Page{

    private $db;
    private $root;
    private $terms;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new db();
        ...
    }

    public function metaDescription($desc){
        echo '
        <meta name="description" content="' . $desc . '" />';
    }

    public function defaultStyles(){     
        echo '
        <link href="' . $this->root . 'css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />';
    }

    ....
}
```

Now, the pages can be anywhere you want them to be, you just set the $root to your absolute website url and all the includes will be correct no matter where your files are being saved.

Comment: 1 little thing. `$page = new page();` must be `$page = new Page();` (Class first letter is uppercase). Unfortunate, I can't change your answer because it's only 1 character change. So sorry for using this way...

Comment: Actually  PHP does not require character case consistency in all instances but it's good practice to use it :)

Comment: Hmm, didn't knew that it wouldn't make an difference. It's never to learn something (although it is bad practice)...

Comment: @ItayGal Thank you for sharing your solution! But I think it would be a bit overkill for my little site ;) But I imagine this would come in very handy for large database dependent sites! Maybe in the future I could make use of this.